# PURE CSS Rotating cube pause at face and then play

Tags: css, rotation, playback, cube, pause

In below example can someone please help to pause a FACE for 8 seconds when the Front, back top is in the view and then to play the animation.

Here is the code:

```css
body {
 color: rgb(6, 106, 117);
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 100%;
 background: #F4F6F8;
 padding: 3em 0 0 0;
 line-height: 62px;
 -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
}

.cube {
 width: 30%;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 100px;

 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -webkit-animation: rotate-cube 10s linear infinite;
}

.front, .bottom, .top, .back {
 background: rgb(247, 247, 247);
 border: 1px solid rgba(147, 184, 189, .8);
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(105, 108, 109, .3), 0 0 8px 5px rgba(208, 223, 226, .4) inset;
 height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.front {
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(50px);
}

.bottom {
 -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(-50px) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(180deg);
}

.top {
 -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-50px) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(180deg);
}

.back {
 -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(50px);
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate-cube {
 0%{-webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);}
 10%{-webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);}
 40%{-webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);}
 60%{-webkit-transform: rotateX(270deg);}
 90%{-webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg);}
 100{-webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<div class="cube">
 <div class="front">
  <h1>Front</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="bottom">
  <h2>Bottom</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="top">
  <h2>Top</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="back">
  <h2>Back</h2>
 </div>
</div>
```

What I need is to pause it for 8 seconds when in Front view, then run to the next FACE, then Pause for 8 Seconds, and then Run to the next view...

Basically, I need to add a pause for each face... Appreciate a help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look here

```css
body {
 color: rgb(6, 106, 117);
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 100%;
 background: #F4F6F8;
 padding: 3em 0 0 0;
 line-height: 62px;
 -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
}

.cube {
 width: 30%;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 100px;

 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -webkit-animation: rotate-cube 33s linear infinite;
}

.front, .bottom, .top, .back {
 background: rgb(247, 247, 247);
 border: 1px solid rgba(147, 184, 189, .8);
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(105, 108, 109, .3), 0 0 8px 5px rgba(208, 223, 226, .4) inset;
 height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.front {
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(50px);
}

.bottom {
 -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(-50px) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(180deg);
}

.top {
 -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-50px) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(180deg);
}

.back {
 -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(50px);
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate-cube {
 0%{-webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);}
  24%{-webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);}
 25%{-webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);}
  49%{-webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);}
 50%{-webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);}
  74%{-webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);}
 75%{-webkit-transform: rotateX(270deg);}
  99%{-webkit-transform: rotateX(270deg);}
 99.999%{-webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg);}
  100%{-webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);}
}
```

```html
<div class="cube">
 <div class="front">
  <h1>Front</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="bottom">
  <h2>Bottom</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="top">
  <h2>Top</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="back">
  <h2>Back</h2>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: O lovely.... This is exactly what I wanted... I did many alone was working 90% You did the Complete! Respect - thanks alot!